# elmah - cannot email exceptions

Tags: elmah

Setting up elmah has been relatively painless for me.  Until I tried to use the email facility.  I have read through all the previous questions on the subject but just can't get it going.  Here are the relevant entries in my web.config file .   This just represents one of the many attempts that I have made, this one using gmail and .  What am I doing wrong?

```
<elmah>
  <errorMail 
    from="myusername@gmail.com" 
    to="me@myemail.com" 
    subject="elmah exception" 
    async="true" 
    smtpPort="0" 
    useSsl="true" />
</elmah>
<system.net> 
  <mailSettings> 
    <smtp deliveryMethod ="Network"> 
      <network 
        host="smtp.gmail.com" 
        port="587" 
        userName="myusername@gmail.com"   
        password="..." /> 
    </smtp> 
  </mailSettings> 
</system.net>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>
```

EDIT
Just to prove the settings, I have managed to successfully send an email from my app using gmail.  The settings used were equivalent and yet I still cannot get elmah to send an email.  Hers is the code snippet.

```
  MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
  mailObj.Subject = "gmail test";
  mailObj.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myusername@gmail.com");
  mailObj.To.Add("test@myemail.com.au");
  mailObj.Body = "Test Email";

  SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
  NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypassword");
  smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
  smtpClient.Port = 587;
  smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
  smtpClient.Send(mailObj);
```

Even some confirmation that it all appears correct would be useful.

Comment: You've misspelled 'smtpPort' in your /elmah/errorMail element - and port 0 probably isn't correct there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my dyslexia,  I will edit the original.  Unfortunately, even with it spelled correctly it still doesn't work.  By setting smtpPort="0" it apparently uses the port specified in the <mailSettings> section.  I have tried the option of explicitly setting the port to 587 but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the port is 465 and the protocol is SSL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but 465 does not work either for me.  I had already set SSL with useSsl="true"

Comment: You can try following this guide, I'm not familiar with elmah so i'm not sure if this will work for you. good luck http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/05/21/163350.aspx Also, if you are using a google apps domain you have to set it to allow external smtp relaying in the admin cp.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider any ill effects from GMail's 2-factor authentication?  I was just having this problem and created an application-specific password for my development work.